# Need a distributed key-value lookup system in PHP

Tags: php, key-value-store, distributed-cache

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198006/need-a-distributed-key-value-lookup-system) asks for one in java,

what's the best candidate in PHP?

BTW,does the following establish:

> distributed key value store ==
>   distributed cache

?

Answer (score 1):

There is *[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)* with advanced cache manipulation functions:

> Redis is an advanced key-value store. It is similar to memcached but the dataset is not volatile, and values can be strings, exactly like in memcached, but also lists, sets, and ordered sets. All this data types can be manipulated with atomic operations to push/pop elements, add/remove elements, perform server side union, intersection, difference between sets, and so forth. Redis supports different kind of sorting abilities.

How is Redis supports distributed servers:

> Redis supports client-side sharding via consistent hashing. Currently there is no support for fail tolerance nor to add or remove clusters at run time.

Comment: I never heard that `Memcached` is distributed.

Comment: Important to note that Memcached is not persistent, as the original question requested.

Comment: BTW, memcached can be used as distributed storage, but it require client side code to choose different server based on some kind of `client_id % number_of_servers` logic.

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev ,really? can you elaborate that logic?

Comment: Here is article about server id calculation based on *key* value for memcached http://www.lastfm.ru/user/RJ/journal/2007/04/10/rz_libketama_-_a_consistent_hashing_algo_for_memcache_clients

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), it is used by Facebook and should be easy to use with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

use MongoDb or Memcached